# How to save attachment from Gmail?

Tags: gmail, attachments

I've got two MP3 files from my friend via Gmail. How can I save them to my phone? There is only a Preview button...

Comment: What version of the Gmail app are you using? What phone? What version of the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I installed the ASTRO file manager and I went to "Preview" - ASTRO popped up, and saying, "give a filename" ok, then it saved the files!! (the files must be ex.: zipped!!) - and then I was able to extract the files in the zip.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have a crippled version of the app.

I emailed myself an mp3 file and got "Download" and "Preview" buttons. Pressing "Download" downloaded the file (as one would expect) to `/sdcard/download`.

(This is an original DROID with Froyo.)

Answer (score 0):

[You can't](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5125), at least not with any consistency, and it looks like you can't request the feature anywhere either. You'll need to use a different email client, or wait for the Google Apps team to implement this out of the blue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a number of apps just for this purpose:

- [Download All Files](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hwkrbbt.downloadall)
- [Save My Attach](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mailtools.saveit)

All of these apps function by becoming options when you click on the Download or Preview button. These are just a couple that I tested out. Download All Files was my favorite. I'm sure there are other apps out there with similar functions.